# XQuery Full text searching over mixed content

Tags: full-text-search, xquery, basex

Following is the XML structure - (i have given a very small piece of the entire document with limited data. I have a XML DB of 6 GB, with proper FULL TEXT Index.)

```
<Docs>
 <Doc>
<Chap>No - 1</Chap>
<Desc>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">departmental report</Para>
  </Notes>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">The equiry commission is good.</Para>
  </Notes>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">departmental process</Para>
    <Para t="ln">The enquiry report for the bomb blast is yet to come.<bL/>
      <bL/>The department working on this is quite lazy.</Para>
  </Notes>
</Desc>
</Doc>
<Doc>
<Chap>No - 2</Chap>
<Desc>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">Enquiry Processes Report</Para>
    <Para t="ln">The enquiry process is very simple.<bL/>
      <bL/>With proper guidance anybody can handle the commission easily.<bL/>
      <bL/>
    </Para>
  </Notes>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">Enquiry - Departmental</Para>
  </Notes>
</Desc>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
<Chap>No - 3</Chap>
<Desc>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">Physics Department</Para>
  </Notes>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">Working process of physics department is quite lengthy</Para>
    <Para t="ln">Even after proper enquiry, I was told nothing.<bL/>
      <bL/>This was like a bomb blast.</Para>
  </Notes>
  <Notes>
    <Para t="sn">Departmental enquiry.</Para>
    <Para t="ln">There should be a departmental enquiry for this wrong process.</Para>
  </Notes>
</Desc>
</Doc>
</Docs>
```

Now I want all those `Chap` nodes containing all words "departmental", "enquiry" and  "report".

So far, I am unable to get them using various combinations. One of my try is -

```
for $x in ft:search("Docs", ("departmental enquiry report"), map{'mode':='all words'})/ancestor::*:Para
 return $x/ancestor::Chap
```

Can any body guide me on this ?

Comment: I am also looking for same kind of solution.

Comment: In such situation which XML DB would be helpful?

Comment: Does Lucene have solution for this?

Comment: With regards to NiksD's question: I know that the multipath indexes in xDB (https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-6822) support this scenario with the option 'include descendants texts' and using the standard XQuery full-text syntax (like Jens Erat showed). I assume that there are other XML databases which support it as well though.

Comment: @EwoutGraswinckel- Thanks for the information. Can you tell me the names of these?

Comment: A general note: Support for descendant full-text indexing will be included in a future release of BaseX (timeline is not yet available).

Comment: @ChristianGrün- Thanks a lot. I am EAGERLY waiting for the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full-text index of BaseX references all terms on text node level. This means that all of your words would need to occur in the same text node.

If you want to take advantage of the full-text query and find all words that occur below a certain element, you could try the following query:

```
let $words := ("departmental enquiry report")
for $doc in db:open("Docs")//Doc[.//text() contains text { $words } any word]
where $doc[string-join(.//text(), ' ') contains text { $words } all words]
return $doc/Chap
```

The first `contains text` expression will be rewritten to an index request. It will return all texts that return any of the searched words. The contains text expression in the `where` clause will filter out all nodes that do not contain all of your query terms. With `string-join(.//text(), ' ')`, all text nodes below the Doc element will be concatenated, and the search will be performed on the joined string.

The folowing, equivalent representation of the query should yield the same results:

```
let $words := ("departmental enquiry report")
for $x in ft:search("Docs", $words, map { 'mode': 'any word' })/ancestor::*:Doc
where ft:contains(string-join($x//text(), ' '), $words, map { 'mode': 'all words' })
return $x/Chap
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still I am not getting the exact result. The above query (first one) is working ONLY when, all the 3 words come under `<Notes>` tag. Say 2 words, out of the 3, comes under one `<Notes>` and remaining 1 under the other `<Notes>`, then NO RESULT, i.e; that `Doc/Chap` is not in result.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried the query. It is now fixed, and I have also revised the text.

Comment: PS: The original query with `.` instead of `string-join(.//text(), ' ')` works if you create the database with the "Chop Whitespaces" flag turned off. This way, all whitespaces between the elements will be stored as extra text nodes. As a result, the size of your database will increase, but the words of different elements will all be separated with enough whitespaces.

Comment: @ChristianGrün -  Thanks for the query. I tried both. But the second query, the one with ft:search, is giving error. "Invalid Key, simple expression expected".

Comment: @Abhit- Its working. Please check the BaseX version. `ft:contains` is available with 7.8. Same issue was with me.

Answer (score 1):

## `ft:search`, and why it Will not Solve the Issue

By looking at [BaseX' XQuery Full Text Documentation](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Full-Text) you will realize that the second argument in `ft:search` should be a sequence of words:

```
ft:search($db as xs:string, $terms as item()*, $options as item()) as text()*
```

So, your query should look something like

```
for $x in ft:search("Docs", ("departmental", "enquiry", "report"), map{'mode':='all words'})/ancestor::*:Para
return $x/ancestor::Chap
```

Yet this still will not solve your issue, as this function

> [re]turns all text nodes from the full-text index of the database `$db` that contain the specified `$terms`.

In other words: all of these words would have to occur in a single text node, but they're spread over multiple in your example input (all over a `<Doc/>` node).

## Using Standard XQuery Full Text

I had to guess from the input and words you're searching for that you actually want to search for `<Doc/>` nodes that contain all these three words.

```
for $document in doc("Docs")/Docs/Doc
where $document contains text { 'departmental', 'enquiry', 'report' } all words
return $document/Chap
```

This will retrieve all documents, apply a full text search on it and finally return the document's chapter node.

Be aware

- I removed the namespace wildcard, as no namespaces are included in your example document and
- to create a full text index (if you didn't do yet) which will highly increase performance.